# Why have conflicting properties for the same class?

Tags: css

I am examining a third party CSS file, and I am coming across the same class that has the same property set multiple times but with different values each time. I cannot figure out why this is, could someone please shed some light on this?

Example below:

```
.tabulator .tabulator-header .tabulator-col {
  display: inline-block;
  position: relative;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  border-right: 1px solid #aaa;
  background: #e6e6e6;
  text-align: left;
  vertical-align: bottom;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.tabulator .tabulator-row .tabulator-cell {
  display: inline-block;
  position: relative;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  padding: 4px;
  border-right: 1px solid #aaa;
  vertical-align: middle;
  white-space: nowrap;
  overflow: hidden;
  text-overflow: ellipsis;
}
```

Comment: I don't understand your question, these classes have different names, they clearly have different purposes. Do you mean why are they used on the same element? If so that just sounds like poor use of HTML/CSS.

Comment: @TomOakley the `tabulator` class is the one I am refering to.

Comment: For one thing these rules are targetting **different** elements. These rules do not set the properties for `.tabulator` **at all**. I would suggest you do some initial reading on how selectors are constructed.

Comment: Maybe `tabulator` is being used for specificity

Comment: @Abs you might want to notice that **.tabulator .class1 .class2** applies the CSS to **class2** and not to tabulator.

Comment: The CSS selector `.tabulator .class1 .class2` won't be used on `<div class="tabulator"></div>`, it's just there to target the elements that succeed `.tabulator` more specifically.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`.tabulator .tabulator-header .tabulator-col{}` - Means that those CSS settings are applied to any HTML element with the class `.tabulator-col` that is inside an element `tabulator-header` and that is inside of an element `tabulator`

So as per your question the both styles are different.

and here is documentation for selectors https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css_selectors.asp

> if two selectors have the same specificity, the last one to be declared wins.

Comment: If that is the problem, this question should be closed rather than answered. But we're not sure that is the problem yet. Maybe the OP just pasted the wrong piece of CSS in by mistake.

Comment: Thanks, I am still new to CSS so I wasn't aware that selectors are used in this manner

Comment: @MrLister Why should it be closed? Is it because the question mis-identified the issue?

Comment: @Abs Yes, because the answer to the question is, "But it doesn't." Sorry.